# Run a job using crontab in CentOS 8 and php remi package

Tags: cron, cron-task

I want to run a cron job every 1st day of each month, I am using the PHP 7.4 remi package.

But whenever I try to do this:

`* * 1 * * php /path/to/php/script`

Nothing is working.

My PHP script is the following:

```
<?php

    // Connect to DB
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=IP;Database=DB", "user", "pass");

    // Reset Tries
    $reset = $conn->prepare("UPDATE trying_count SET Tries = 0");
    $reset->execute();

?>
```

Do I need to install the PHP-CLI or something else?

Comment: "Nothing is working." is obviously "not a good description"

Comment: The sccript is not running, that's what I mean